# VS2012 Update 4 changes to Publishing Projects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I've just installed an update to VS2012 (Update 4), and significant changes have been made with publishing projects (in my case a website).

It now seems that 'Build->Publish Website' is now wizard based, with most of the standard options and a few extras. However I seem to be having the following problems:

- When publishing, in configuration there used to be 'Debug' and 'Release'. Release has disappeared for me, but I wish to publish to a production environment.

I don't want to publish a debug version, however the live web.config has <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" /> - Would this be enough, or do I need to somehow get the 'Release' option back when publishing?

Has anyone else had these problems, or is it isolated to my setup?

Thanks muchly! Radderz

Edit: I have removed some problems which fixed themselves after a build issue was solved. I previously must have had the precompile and delete options off by accident, as those problems are no longer occurring.